Back buffer texture appears distorted before presenting
I am trying to send video data from Dolphin Emulator to another process. To do so, I first get a reference to the back buffer from the swap chain.
// in file: D3DGfx.cpp 
// in function: void Gfx::PresentBackBuffer()
  HRESULT hr = m_swap_chain->GetDXGISwapChain()->GetBuffer(
      0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(back_buffer.GetAddressOf()));

I then create a shared texture and do a GPU -> GPU copy so I can modify the texture later.
  D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
  ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> shared_texture;

  back_buffer->GetDesc(&desc);

  desc.BindFlags = 0;
  desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;

  hr = D3D::device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, shared_texture.GetAddressOf());

  D3D::context->CopyResource(shared_texture.Get(), back_buffer.Get());

Then, I create a shared handle, and map it to shared memory with my other process for reading.
  hr = shared_texture.As(&dxgi_resource);
  hr = dxgi_resource->GetSharedHandle(&shared_handle);
  void* pMappedMem = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0,
                                   32);  // map 32 bytes into the virtual address space
  struct SharedTextureData sd;
  sd.handle = shared_handle;
  sd.width = width;
  sd.height = height;
  if (pMappedMem)
  {
    std::memcpy(pMappedMem, &sd, sizeof(SharedTextureData));
    UnmapViewOfFile(pMappedMem);
  }

However, before sharing the texture, I wanted to debug the texture to make sure I was sending the proper data. So I created a staging texture, mapped the resource, and saved to png to view the texture.
  desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;  // Allow CPU read access
  desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
  ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> staging_texture;
  hr = D3D::device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, staging_texture.GetAddressOf());
  D3D::context->CopyResource(staging_texture.Get(), shared_texture.Get());

  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
  hr = D3D::context->Map(stagingTexture.Get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);

  BYTE* data = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(mappedResource.pData);
  UINT rowPitch = mappedResource.RowPitch;

  //save to png
  stbi_write_png("output.png", width, height, 4, data, rowPitch);

This is the texture that was saved.

For reference, this is what the texture looks like after being drawn to the screen by Dolphin Emulator.

Things I have tried to resolve this issue but did not change anything or made it worse:

Ensure that the format is correct (DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM)

Adjust the format to be PNG-compatible:
  for (UINT i = 0; i < desc.Height; ++i)
  {
    for (UINT j = 0; j < mappedResource.RowPitch; j += 4)
    {
      UINT offset = (i * desc.Width + j);
      data[offset] = (data[offset] >> 2) & 0x3F;
      data[offset + 1] = (data[offset] >> 2) & 0x3F;
      data[offset + 2] = (data[offset] >> 2) & 0x3F;
      data[offset + 3] = (data[offset] >> 2) & 0x3F;

    }
  }

This results in the following texture:


Resolve the texture to a single sample (if it was multi-sampled) before copying to the
staging texture
  desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
  desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;  // Resolve to a single sample
  desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

  ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> resolvedTexture;
  hr = D3D::device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, resolvedTexture.GetAddressOf());

  D3D::context->CopyResource(resolvedTexture.Get(), backBuffer.Get());

  D3D::context->ResolveSubresource(resolvedTexture.Get(), 0, backBuffer.Get(), 0,
                                   desc.Format);




If anyone could identify what the cause of the distortion might be, or suggest a better technique or a different approach entirely, I would greatly appreciate it.

I think png doesn't supports 10:10:10:2 format. You have to convert it to something like 8:8:8:8 or another (see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2083#page-16). See also https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex. It might have something to help in the conversion. Otherwise you have to manually convert the 10:10:10:2 to 8:8:8:8. You would have to map that 2 bit channel to 8 bit channel for the png format. So something like 00 -> Fully transparent and 11->  Opaque. But you have to decide for 01 and 10 mapping. And also you have to take the byte order into consideration i.e RGBA or ABGR.
